# Use jq to turn x=y pairs into key/value pairs

Tags: json, parsing, key, environment-variables, jq

I'm trying to parse environment variables from the JSON output of `docker inspect`.  Annoyingly, those environment variables aren't returned as useful key-value pairs.  They're just an array of x=y strings.  Here's a relevant snippet of the output:

```json
[
    {
        "Config": {
            "Env": [
                "JENKINS_HOST=1.2.3.4",
                "JENKINS_INSTANCE=tea",
                "JENKINS_NAME=Enterprise Architecture Tools",
                "JENKINS_VERSION=2.46.2",
                "JENKINS_PROTOCOL=http"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to convert that array into something like this:

```json
{
  "Config": {
    "Env": {
      "JENKINS_HOST": "1.2.3.4",
      "JENKINS_INSTANCE": "tea",
      "JENKINS_NAME": "Enterprise Architecture Tools",
      "JENKINS_VERSION": "2.46.2",
      "JENKINS_PROTOCOL": "http"
    }
  }
}
```

That way, I can use a command like `jq '.[] | .Config.Env.JENKINS_HOST'` to get the values that I care about.  I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

It's relatively easy to select the data and even split the key and value into separate elements.  For instance, if I use `jq '.[] | .Config.Env | .[] | split("=")'`, I get data like this:

```json
[
  "JENKINS_HOST",
  "1.2.3.4"
]
[
  "JENKINS_INSTANCE",
  "tea"
]
[
  "JENKINS_NAME",
  "Enterprise Architecture Tools"
]
[
  "JENKINS_VERSION",
  "2.46.2"
]
[
  "JENKINS_PROTOCOL",
  "http"
]
```

However, I can't figure out how to turn that data into an object assignment.  It seems like it should probably be some combination of `map` or `reduce`, but I'm stumped.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To convert an array of two strings (e.g. ["k", "v"]) to an object, you can write:

```
{ (.[0]) : .[1] }
```

So you'll want to write something like:

```
 map(.Config.Env |= (map( split("=") | { (.[0]) : .[1] } ) | add))
```

#### a2o

Abstracting out the array-to-object functionality makes the solution a bit more digestible:

```
def a2o: map( split("=") | { (.[0]) : .[1] } ) | add;

map(.Config.Env |= a2o)
```

#### Using `match` or `capture` instead of `split`

Since it is possible for an "=" character to appear in the "value" part of each `var=value` string, using `split` naively might not be such a great idea.  Here is a more robust alternative, assuming your jq supports regular expressions:

```
match("([^=]*)=(.*)") | .captures | {(.[0].string) : .[1].string}
```

Or, slightly more succinctly and perhaps elegantly:

```
[capture( "(?<key>[^:]*):(?<value>.*)" )] | from_entries
```

#### `index/1`

If your jq does not have regex support, you could use `index/1`, along these lines:

```
index("=") as $ix | {(.[:$ix]) : .[$ix+1:]}
```

Comment: Excellent!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Nice and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Given collection of items to convert to a single object, I generally would opt to using `reduce` for this purpose. Turn those items to their constituent keys and values, then assign to the result object.

```
reduce (.[] | split("=")) as [$key, $value] ({}; .[$key] = $value)
```

Though using `from_entries` is also useful here as well, instead you'd create an array of the key/value objects that it expects.

```
map(split("=") as [$key, $value] | {$key, $value}) | from_entries
```

Then put it all together with the update of the `Env` property using whichever method you choose.

```
.[].Config.Env |= reduce (.[] | split("=")) as [$key, $value] ({}; .[$key] = $value)
#or
.[].Config.Env |= (map(split("=") as [$key, $value] | {$key, $value}) | from_entries)
```

https://jqplay.org/s/qfItW5U-Tf