# jq to convert two text strings into a single json object

Tags: json, bash, sh, text-processing, jq

How do I convert these two text strings into a single json object

Text strings:

```
start process: Mon May 15 03:14:09 UTC 2017
logfilename: log_download_2017
```

Json output:

```
{
"start process": "Mon May 15 03:14:09 UTC 2017",
"logfilename": "log_download_2017",
}
```

Shell script:

```
logfilename="log_download_2017"
echo "start process: $(date -u)" | tee -a $logfilename.txt | jq -R . >> $logfilename.json
echo "logfilename:" $logfilename | tee -a $logfilename.txt | jq -R . >> $logfilename.json
```

Comment: Frankly, I guessed that this was what you really wanted in the other question, even though *as asked* it explicitly wanted each (key, value) pair to be in a separate map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned e.g. at [Use jq to turn x=y pairs into key/value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729643/use-jq-to-turn-x-y-pairs-into-key-value-pairs), the basic task of converting a key:value string can be accomplished in a number of ways. For example, you could start with:

```
index(":") as $ix | {(.[:$ix]) : .[$ix+1:]}
```

You evidently want to trim some spaces, which can be done using `sub/2`.

To combine the objects, you could use `add`.  To do this in a single pass, you would use jq -R -s

Putting it all together, you could do worse than:

```
def trim: sub("^ +";"") | sub(" +$";"");

def s2o:
  (index(":") // empty) as $ix
  | {(.[:$ix]): (.[$ix+1:]|trim)};

split("\n") | map(s2o) | add
```

Comment: Thank you again, elegant code and simple explanations. It works nicely, and as suggested yesterday, when implemented through an approach like piping all input commands with exec. I now have to combine this together with yesterdays text processing solution for strings into an array and build a single json object. I will try again to implement one exec processing section at the start and another at the end. It has two parts; combining the jq programs and the exec pipe handling for each jq program.Would it be sensible to ask these as a separate questions?