# Turning list of headers and list of values into valid json with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm working with an endpoint like this:

```
curl -S www.example.com 
[[\"A", "B", "C", "D"]\n
["1","2",null,"4"]]
```

I'd like to use jq to change this response into proper json rather than a list of headers and a row of data corresponding to the items in the list:

```
{"A": "1", "B": "2", "C" : null, "D": "4"}
```

However, what seems like the obvious answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729713/1052117)

of

```
curl -S www.example.com  | jq '{(.[0]) : .[1] }'
```

produces

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot use array (["A...) as object key
```

And

```
curl -S www.example.com  | jq '{.[0] : .[1] }'
```

produces

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '.' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
{.[0] : .[1] } 
jq: 1 compile error
```

What's the right syntax for

```
[[HEADER1,HEADER2,...]\n
[DATA1,DATA2]]
```

responses into json?

Are the unquoted null and the newline the source of my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what's posted, the output of the curl command is so weird that it would require special processing.  Chances are the output is not as weird as shown, and the `sed` command shown as part of the solution below might need tweaking.

In any case, with the input as shown:

```
sed 's/\\"/"/;1s/\\n/,/' input.txt | jq '
  .[0] as $h
  | .[1] 
  | . as $in
  | reduce range(0;length) as $i
      ({}; .[$h[$i]] = $in[$i])'
```

produces the desired output.

### One-stop shopping

```
jq -Rs < input.txt '
  split("\n")
  | map(select(length>0))
  | ( .[0] | sub("[[]\\\\"; "") | sub("\\\\n"; "") | fromjson) as $h
  | .[1]
  | sub("\\]\\]"; "]")
  | fromjson
  | . as $in
  | reduce range(0;length) as $i
      ({}; .[$h[$i]] = $in[$i])'
```

Comment: Wow, you are very skilled at jq.  Thank you!