# Convert key = value pairs to JSON

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to convert a file containing key = value pairs into JSON.
This file might contain Windows EOL (`\r\n`) and empty lines.

Given the following input (mind the empty lines):

```
foo = aa
bar = bb

qux = cc
white space = white space
* = special-char
```

This is the expected result:

```
{
  "foo": "aa",
  "bar": "bb",
  "qux": "cc",
  "white space": "white space",
  "*": "special-char"
}
```

I managed to go this far:

```
{
  "foo": "aa"
}
{
  "bar": "bb"
}
{
  "qux": "cc"
}
{
  "white space": "white space"
}
{
  "*": "special-char"
}
```

Using the following command:

```
 jq --raw-input 'split("\n") | map(split(" = ") | { (.[0]): .[1] }) | .[]'
```

But I can not figure out the missing bit. What is missing or is this a better way to achieve this?

**Edit:** added constraint about empty line and Windows EOL

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but please note that this question has been asked (in slightly different forms) and answered on stackoverflow.com e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729643/use-jq-to-turn-x-y-pairs-into-key-value-pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close. Drop `\r`s at the end, split by `=`, transform resulting arrays into objects, put them into an array and pass it to `add`.

```
[ inputs
  | gsub("\r$"; "")
  | split(" = "; "")
  | select(length == 2)
  | {(.[0]): .[1]}
] | add
```

You need `--raw-input`/`-R` and `--null-input`/`-n` options specified on the command line in order for this to work.

Comment: What about cases where the input might contain empty lines? If ```[inputs | select(length > 0) | split(" = ") | {(.[0]): .[1]}] | add``` deals with empty lines, it leaves ```\r``` in the values when the file contains Windows EOL.

Comment: @woodpeck_ Your original question didn't mention DOS line endings or empty/blank lines in the input, how could I have known?

Comment: you couldn't, I am not blaming you :-) Thank you for you answer. I realized after trying your solution out that my OP was lacking some information so I updated it.

Comment: @woodpeck_ updated accordingly. next time you ask a question make sure there is no need for updates that might invalidate already provided answers

Comment: it does work now with both ```--raw-input``` and ```--null-input``` (the absence of this second option removed the first item). From the manual: --null-input/-n → Don't read any input at all! Instead, the filter is run once using null as the input. This is useful when using jq as a simple calculator or to construct JSON data from scratch.

Comment: @woodpeck_ manual might be misleading, apparently maintainers don't put much effort on documenting their software

Answer (score 1):

If one of the "values" contains an "=" then using `split("=")` naively will produce incorrect results. If your jq supports `capture`, then here is a solution that avoids that issue:

```
jq -nR '
  def trim: sub("^ +";"") | sub(" +$";"");
  [inputs
   | select(index("="))
   | sub("\r$"; "")
   | capture( "(?<key>[^=]*)=(?<value>.*)" )
   | ( (.key |= trim) | (.value |= trim)) ]
  | from_entries'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is an interesting approach too. You probably want to swap that ```?<key>[^=]*``` with ```?<key>[^=]+``` to avoid empty keys (empty values are fine though)