# How to convert semicolon separated parameters to json?

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

I have these variables in bash.

```
DOC='ABC=123;CDE=345;CDE=IOP'
NEWVAR='101808'
NEWVAR2='10240404'
```

I want to combine them and create a json string in bash.

```
{
   "ABC": "123",
   "CDE": "345",
   "CDE": "IOP",
   "NEWVAR": "101808",
   "NEWVAR2": "10240404"
}
```

only 'DOC' is in semicolon-separated values.
NEWVAR and NEWVAR2 are just plain texts.

can I use jq to do this?

Comment: You can't have 2 `CDE` keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the duplicate `CDE` key, we can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729643/use-jq-to-turn-x-y-pairs-into-key-value-pairs) to convert the `;` splitter string into separate values, then using `add` to create a object:

```
$DOC | split(";") | map(split("=") | { (.[0]) : .[1] }) | add + { $NEWVAR } + { $NEWVAR2 }
```

Where

- `split(";") | map(split("=") | { (.[0]) : .[1] })` is from the link above
- `add` created the objecct
- `+ { $NEWVAR }` combine the simple `NEWVAR` to the object
- `+ { $NEWVAR2 }` Add `NEWVAR2`

---

Full command with `--arg`:

```
jq --arg DOC "$DOC" --arg NEWVAR "$NEWVAR" --arg NEWVAR2 "$NEWVAR2" '$DOC | split(";") | map(split("=") | { (.[0]) : .[1] }) | add + { $NEWVAR } + { $NEWVAR2 }' -Rn
```

---

Example on my local machine:

```
$ DOC='ABC=123;CDE=345;CDE=IOP'
NEWVAR='101808'
NEWVAR2='10240404'
$
$ jq --arg DOC "$DOC" --arg NEWVAR "$NEWVAR" --arg NEWVAR2 "$NEWVAR2" '$DOC | split(";") | map(split("=") | { (.[0]) : .[1] }) | add + { $NEWVAR } + { $NEWVAR2 }' -Rn
{
  "ABC": "123",
  "CDE": "IOP",
  "NEWVAR": "101808",
  "NEWVAR2": "10240404"
}
$
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
DOC='ABC=123;CDE=345;CDE=IOP'
NEWVAR='101808'
NEWVAR2='10240404'
args=()

# parse $DOC and add jq --arg options to the array
while IFS='=' read -r -d ';' name value || [[ -n $name && -n $value ]]; do
    args+=( --arg "$name" "$value" )
done < <(printf '%s' "$DOC")

# add the plain variables to the array
for var in NEWVAR NEWVAR2; do
    args+=( --arg "$var" "${!var}" )
done

declare -p args

jq --null-input  "${args[@]}" '$ARGS.named'
```

outputs

```
declare -a args=([0]="--arg" [1]="ABC" [2]="123" [3]="--arg" [4]="CDE" [5]="345" [6]="--arg" [7]="CDE" [8]="IOP" [9]="--arg" [10]="NEWVAR" [11]="101808" [12]="--arg" [13]="NEWVAR2" [14]="10240404")
{
  "ABC": "123",
  "CDE": "345",
  "NEWVAR": "101808",
  "NEWVAR2": "10240404"
}
```

jq clearly ignores duplicate --arg variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 CDE keys.

Using sed and [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) you can run

```
<input.csv sed "s/'//g" | \
mlr --x2n --ips = nest --explode --pairs --across-records -f DOC  --nested-ps =  then \
unsparsify then \
reshape -r "[A-Z]" -o i,v then \
filter -x -S '$v==""' then \
uniq -a
```

to have

```
ABC 123
NEWVAR 101808
NEWVAR2 10240404
CDE 345
CDE IOP
```

And than you can write a loop to create the wrong JSON you want.

If you want a JSON run

```
<input.csv sed "s/'//g" | \
mlr --x2j --ips = nest --explode --pairs --across-records -f DOC  --nested-ps =  then \
unsparsify then \
reshape -r "[A-Z]" -o i,v then \
filter -x -S '$v==""' then \
uniq -a then reshape -s i,v
```

to have

```
{ "ABC": 123, "NEWVAR": 101808, "NEWVAR2": 10240404, "CDE": "IOP" }
```